# How to keep QPushButton pressed when working in a linked page?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6, qt6

I have a pyQt6 interface where I have two QPushButtons btn1 and btn2. And I have a QStackedWidget with two pages, page1 and page2. Now I when I press btn1, i want page1 to appear. On clicking btn2, page2 should appear. But when I am on page1 btn1 should stay pressed or lets say always highlighted and same goes for btn2 when I am on page2. How do I do that in pyQt6?

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:pressed,\n"
        "QPushButton:clicked,\n"
        "QPushButton:checked,\n"
        "QPushButton:hover {\n"
        "    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
        "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 75, 24))
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("\n"
        "\n"
        "")
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 75, 24))
        self.btn2.setObjectName("btn2")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 40, 361, 221))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page1.setObjectName("page1")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page1)
        self.page2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page2.setObjectName("page2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    self.btn2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

## this is what I tried but didn't work

```
self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1Clicked)  #or should i select 'pressed' or 'toggled'signal instead      

self.ui.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2Clicked)

def btn1Clicked(self):
        self.ui.stackWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page1)

        if self.ui.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(0):
            self.ui.btn1.setCheckable(True)
        else:
            self.ui.btn1.setCheckable(False)
```

Comment: [`checkable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) is not the same as [`checked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop). Making a button *checkable* means that it *can* be checked, but it doesn't automatically *make it checked*.

Comment: Great. So I did setCheckable(True) and chnaged setChecked(True) and setChecked(False). It worked, thanks a lot.